# Why does the substance with lower polarizability carry an anionic surface charge when immersed in a high dielectric constant medium?

Tags: charge, polarization

[image]

I'm learning about electric double layer (EDL), and so I was watching this short [animated video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HDQ8ct4md-8&list=RDQM_zfRyFs8DmQ&index=1) that explains the mechanism of the formation of this double layer.

The reason I have the question (why does the substance with lower polarizability carry an anionic surface charge?) is because in the video they mentioned that when a solid particle is immersed in water, if the solid particle has low dielectric constant compared to water then the surface of the particle will carry anionic surface charge (negative charges on its surface).

So, why does the substance with lower polarizability carry an anionic surface charge?